# ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died! java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm getting this following error while executing a java code which is using Kafka into Storm.

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died! java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null
```

Comment: Without any proper context, no one is able to help. Elaborate more and show configuration