# BufferUnderflowException from storm kafka spout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

maybe same thing going on here: [ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died! java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879748/error-backtype-storm-util-async-loop-died-java-nio-bufferunderflowexception) but I am going to add a full stack trace and some more context.

storm version - 9.3
storm-kafka version - 9.3
kafka version - 0.8.2-beta

I am also using trident, although I think this error is happening at the storm level.

stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException  
  at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-   0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3441$fn__3453$fn__3500.invoke(executor.clj:748) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]  
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null
  at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:498) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
  at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
  at kafka.api.OffsetResponse$.readFrom(OffsetResponse.scala:28) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
  at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:128) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
  at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
  at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:77) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:67) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.doEmitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:111) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.failFastEmitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:72) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.emitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:79) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.access$000(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:46) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter$1.emitPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:204) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter$1.emitPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:194) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor$Emitter.emitBatch(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:127) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.trident.spout.TridentSpoutExecutor.execute(TridentSpoutExecutor.java:82) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:369) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3441$tuple_action_fn__3443.invoke(executor.clj:633) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3364.invoke(executor.clj:401) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1447.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:125) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
```

Spout code (note I'm using a statically defined partition map with only one broker for debugging purposes):

```
Broker broker = new Broker("localhost", 9094);
GlobalPartitionInformation partitionInfo = new GlobalPartitionInformation();
partitionInfo.addPartition(0, broker);
StaticHosts hosts = new StaticHosts(partitionInfo);
TridentKafkaConfig spoutConfig = new TridentKafkaConfig(hosts, kafkaTopic);

spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = -1L;
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
return new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

Comment: this could be due to problem in the TopicMeta data..are you able to consume from the topic using the cosole-script shipped with Kafka?

Comment: im pretty sure its a meta data thing and has to do with how im trying to read from a multi-node cluster. if i get a definite answer i'll post it.

Comment: its a single cluster that has been considered here .. if the console script is able to consumer messages it implies the topic is not corrupted and problem could be at your end.

Answer (score 0):

This exception may be spawned when congestion occurs on disruptor queues especially send queue of spout. i suggest that you increase executor send buffer size. it may solve the issue.